# Have existing JavaScript that smooth scrolls to id's, would like help adding an exception for a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The JavaScript here will smooth scroll to all hash links. I need the `id=nav` and its resulting hash link, `/#nav` to be ignored by the below JavaScript. `id=nav` is used in the menu responsiveness and when it is commandeered by the below JavaScript it breaks the menu.

Can someone please advise how I can ignore a specific id in the below JavaScript?

Also I made a working HTML demo you can seen below.

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}
#nav {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: block;
}
#test1 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
}
#test2 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #111;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <a href="#nav">nav</a>

    <a href="#test1">1</a>

    <a href="#test2">2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="nav"></div>

  <div id="test1"></div>

  <div id="test2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just use a conditional to check for the specific hash you don't want to scroll to? Would improve readability too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line right after the 2nd line of JavaScript:

```
if($(this).attr("href") == "#nav") return;
```

So it looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href") == "#nav") return;
        //... Rest of code
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/funL21hy/1/)

**How this works** is it checks that the `href` attribute's value of the clicked link isn't `"#nav"`. If it is, the function returns `false` and isn't executed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does technically work, but it still does not work for me as it seems to be disabling the hash rather than the effect of the js specifically. 

Without my js clicking on the hash reveals the responsive nav via css [intended effect], with my js the hash only scrolls, with your fix it seems to remove the effect of the hash all together and clicking does nothing.

Comment: @TaylorOsborn Okay, I have updated my answer. Would you maybe please try it again?

Comment: Nice concise fix. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition in your selector, or combine with a .not selector as below.

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}
#nav {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: block;
}
#test1 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
}
#test2 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #111;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('[href="#nav"]').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault; return false;}); // Use this line if you don't want to go to top. Personally I would not use anchors if their base functionality is removed.
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').not('[href="#nav"]').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <a href="#nav">nav</a>

    <a href="#test1">1</a>

    <a href="#test2">2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="nav"></div>

  <div id="test1"></div>

  <div id="test2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This won't work as if you click the nav link, it still goes to the top of the page, even though it doesn't scroll smoothly.

Comment: The script is not applied. If you don't want to scroll why use an anchor? You can of course preventDefault it (I'll edit the answer).

Comment: I don't know why the OP used an anchor, just wanted to point it out though.

Comment: Tyvm. I added a prevent default with a comment regarding that :).

Comment: Hey all, thank you so much for the help. So same as with the other solution,
this does technically work, but it seems to be disabling the hash rather than the effect of the js specifically. 

Without my js clicking on the hash reveals the responsive nav via css [intended effect], with my js the hash only scrolls, with your fix it seems to remove the effect of the hash all together and clicking does nothing

Comment: No need to spend more time though, I have a working model already. Thanks again!